# How to pass different arguments to each group in grouping of data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

**Example:**

Here is a data table called `dt`:

```
> library(data.table)
> dt <- data.table(colA=rep(letters[1:3],each=3), colB=0:8)
> dt
   colA colB
1:    a    0
2:    a    1
3:    a    2
4:    b    3
5:    b    4
6:    b    5
7:    c    6
8:    c    7
9:    c    8
```

I want to know:

For `colA` equals "a", is there any values in `colB` > 2?

For `colA` equals "b", is there any values in `colB` > 3?

For `colA` equals "c", is there any values in `colB` > 4?

I create a vector called `arg` to hold arguments for group "a", "b" & "c":

> arg <- c(2,3,4)

Could anyone give me a simple way to pass `arg` to grouping of `dt` by `colA`?

Here is my desired result:

```
     colA    V1
  1:    a FALSE
  2:    b  TRUE
  3:    c  TRUE
```

This is my first question here and I tried to make it simple. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For each subgroup that it operates on, `[.data.table()` stores information about the current value(s) of the grouping variable(s) in a variable named `.BY`.

If you first set up a named vector that maps the grouping variable's levels to the desired parameter values, you can use `.BY` to index into it, extracting the appropriate values, like so:

```
arg <- setNames(c(2, 3, 4), c("a", "b", "c"))
arg
# a b c 
# 2 3 4

dt[, any(colB > arg[unlist(.BY)]), by="colA"]
#    colA    V1
# 1:    a FALSE
# 2:    b  TRUE
# 3:    c  TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dt[ , thresh := (2:4)[as.numeric(factor(colA))] ]
dt

   colA colB thresh
1:    a    0      2
2:    a    1      2
3:    a    2      2
4:    b    3      3
5:    b    4      3
6:    b    5      3
7:    c    6      4
8:    c    7      4
9:    c    8      4

dt[, any(colB > thresh),by=colA]

   colA    V1
1:    a FALSE
2:    b  TRUE
3:    c  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most elegant way, but I will give it a shot...

```
#List components of each group
ref <- dt[,list(colB.list=list(I(colB))),by=colA][,ord:=.I]

#Feed arguements
ref[,arg:=c(2,3,4)]

#Use comparison function
ref[,V1:=mapply(FUN=function(X,Y){sum(colB.list[[X]]>Y)>0},X=ord,Y=arg)]
```

Comment: It works! It's good to point out `mapply`. Let's see if there is a simpler solution.